# Como trazer um array via ajax e colocar resultados em um select

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, codeigniter

Olá, estou tentando trazer um array via ajax e jogar o resultado em um select, eu consigo fazer uma consulta via ajax aonde cada cliente que eu seleciono em um select ele faz a consulta via ajax e retorna os serviços vinculado a esse cliente em um array,até aqui deu certo, só que travei nessa parte de mostrar os dados do array, eu precisava pegar a coluna, id_produto e nome_produto mas não consigo kk to aprendendo ainda, quem puder me ajudar agradeço. Meu código está assim:

```
 //Função trazer serviços vinculados ao cliente
        $(document).on("change", "#cliente", function(){
           
            var id_cliente = $('[name=cliente]').val();
        
             $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"http://[::1]/admin/clientes/servicoCliente",                
                 data:{input_id:id_cliente},
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (resposta){
 
                   if (resposta.erro == 0) {
                      
                      var select = '<option value='+ resposta.listar_servico[id_produto] +' ' + resposta.listar_servico[nome_produto] + '>' + resposta.listar_servico[nome_produto] + '</option>';
                                                        
                      $('#servicos').html(select);      
                      console.log(resposta.listar_servico);
                      
                   } else{
 
                      alert('Erro ao trazer serviços');
                   }
 
                 },
                 error:function(){
                     console.log(resposta);
                     alert('Erro ao trazer serviços.');
                 }
            });
 
        });

//Aqui meu php onde deveria retornar a resposta do ajax
 <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                      <label>Serviço:</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-15">
                      <select name="servicos" id="servicos" class="form-control">
                        
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

E no console ele traz a resposta assim:

```
listar_servico: [{idcli: "7", nome: "José Gonçalves", id_produto: "1", pedi: "24",…},…]
0: {idcli: "7", nome: "José Gonçalves", produtos: "1", pedi: "24",…}
data_cadastro: "2020-04-14"
idcli: "7"
nome: "José Gonçalves"
nome_produto: "Software"
notapen: "7"
pedi: "24"
id_produto: "1"
total_pedido: "119.00"

1: {idcli: "7", nome: "José Gonçalves", produtos: "2", pedi: "27",…}
data_cadastro: "2020-05-05"
idcli: "7"
nome: "José Gonçalves"
nome_produto: "Suporte Web Site"
notapen: "7"
pedi: "27"
id_produto: "2"
total_pedido: "80.00"
msg: "Pedido atualizado com sucesso"
```

E eu precisava apensa da coluna id_produto e nome_produto pra preencher meu select, quem puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Olá, tente mostrar a resposta no php assim: <?php
if(isset($_POST['listar_servico'])) {
    $data = json_decode($_POST['listar_servico']);
    print_r($listar_servico);
}

Comment: oii, já tentei mas não funciona tb... :(

Comment: estranho, vou tentar colocar outra resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloca o ajax:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

E agora tenta assim:

```
 //Função trazer serviços vinculados ao cliente
        $(document).on("change", "#cliente", function(){
           
            var id_cliente = $('[name=cliente]').val();
             $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"http://[::1]/admin/bd_cadastrados/servicoCliente",                
                 data:{input_id:id_cliente},
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (resposta){
 
                   if (resposta.erro == 0) {
                                                            
                    var select = '<option value="">Selecione o Serviço</option>';
                       $.each(resposta.listar_servico, function (index, value){
                    select = select + '<option value="' + value.id_produto + '">' + value.nome_produto + '</option>';
                   });
                     $('#servicos').html(select);
  
                      console.log(resposta.listar_servico);
                      
                   } else{
 
                      alert('Erro ao trazer serviços');
                   }
 
                 },
                 error:function(){
                     console.log(resposta);
                     alert('Erro ao trazer serviços.');
                 }
            });
 
        });
```

Comment: tentei tb, mas continua com o select vazio, ele traz os resultados em array no console, mas no select ele não exibe nada, não sei mais o que fazer.. :(

Comment: Editei o codigo e acrescentei o ajax, veja se é isso.

Comment: Funcionou, perfeitamente, mto obrigado, desculpe a minha burrice, valew mesmo.

Comment: kk De nada, ninguém é burro apenas estamos aprendendo.. fico feliz por ajudar.. :)